# AVD/Eclipse Mobile network settings "Data Enabled" bug

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Whenever I untick "Data Enabled"(Settings->Mobile network settings) within my AVD I get the following error, I lose LogCat connectivity, and I have to restart the AVD/Eclipse :

```
[2012-10-31 16:11:07 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:752)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:462)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is this behaviour expected? Can I do something to "re-attach" LogCat?

edit: I tried this in a second computer. This time no error logs, but still LogCat communication is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the data communication that is disabled when deselecting "data enabled" include the one which is used by logcat to connect to the phone (I always thought it was some sort of serial port, but I guess it uses the network, instead..).

So, I'm pretty sure there is no workaround around this, i.e. you cannot communicate with the avd while communication with the avd is turned off; however, since afaik logcat acts kind of like a `tail -f logfile`, you should be able to read the "missed" log entries once you turn data back on and reconnect logcat to the device (if it doesn't do that automatically, there should be a reconnect option, if not, you can still use the command-line tools from the sdk to read the log).